# Laravel Artisan & imap_open()

Tags: php, laravel, email, imap

Currently experiencing a weird bug or something I might be overseeing. (Laravel framework)

I have a plain HomeController where I am doing a succesful imap_open() connection. ( I can read out the complete mailbox using the browser )

But once I transport this function to an artisan command, it returns me:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Call to undefined function App\Console\Commands\imap_open()
```

What am I missing or is this just plain not possible?

Comment: As stated, the function is missing in `App\Console\Commands`, if you added it correctly, please edit your post with the code.

Comment: imap_open() is a default function in PHP (which is enabled in my installation because the same code works in a browser): http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

Answer (score 0):

You try to be able to call it though `Artisan`, but you need to add an `Artisan` function since `Artisan` can't know what you want to do, please check the documentation section `Writing Commands` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan).

For now you're calling an unknown `Artisan` function that's why you get this

Answer (score 0):

Your code is currently in the App\Console\Command namespace.

Because you are calling the imap_open function without specifying the namespace, it is looking for a App\Console\Command\imap_open function and can't find it.

Because it's a default php function, the key here is to call it in the global namespace using a \

So make sure you call it like that:

```
 $res = \imap_open(...params);
```

Also make sure the imap is compiled/enabled for the php cli (as the php.ini for cli is different from the web one)

Comment: I tried this indeed, but this results in a:

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Call to undefined function imap_open()

Comment: Controllers are run in a web context, Artisan Commands are run in a cli context. The two doesn't have the same php.ini. Can you please check that the imap extension is enabled for php-cli?

Comment: Do you have a quick solution on how to check this?

Comment: Find the php.ini used by php-cli (depend on your setup), then check the extension line isn't commented out.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it by compiling PHP with IMAP this way: http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=341